How to complete fromEventPattern to prevent re-subscription?
I'm writing some code that uses fromEventPattern to subscribe/unsubscribe to a third party event handler.
Caveat: in the example code i'm using document click with fromEventPattern for demonstration purposes only
It should:

Subscribe on a user action - multiple subscriptions to the outer$ observable are allowed
The inner click$ observable (fromEventPattern) should only ever subscribe once, on the initial subscription to the outer$ observable - so only one handler should ever be added through document.addEventListener
When a specific condition is met a function is called to complete the outer$ observable - this should then cause the inner click$ observable to also be unsubscribed, thus document.removeEventListener will be called and the handler removed
Any further attempts to re-subscribe to the outer$ observable should do nothing once it's been completed

In the demo do the following:

Open the browser console
Click the Subscribe button (as many times as you like)
Click anywhere in the preview pane
Click the Complete button

Attempted Solution
function addClickHandler(handler: (event: MouseEvent) => void) {
  console.log('added click handler');
  document.addEventListener('click', handler);
}

function removeClickHandler(handler: (event: MouseEvent) => void) {
  console.log('removed click handler');
  document.removeEventListener('click', handler);
}

const click$ = fromEventPattern(addClickHandler, removeClickHandler);

const destroy = new Subject();
const destroy$ = destroy.asObservable();

const outer = new BehaviorSubject<MouseEvent | undefined>(undefined);
const outer$ = outer.asObservable().pipe(
  switchMap(() => click$),
  takeUntil(destroy$),
  share()
);

function subscribe() {
  outer$.subscribe({
    next: console.log,
    complete: () => console.log('completed'),
  });
}

function unsubscribe() {
  destroy.next(true);
  destroy.complete();
  outer.complete();
}

Question
The solution works but i get the feeling there's probably a more succinct/better way to solve this without the need for a BehaviourSubject and having to complete both the destroy and outer Observable.
Any ideas?

Instead of explicitly creating a subscription when you click "Subscribe", you can simply use mergeMap to internally subcribe when click$ emits.
mergeMap will create a subscription to the inner observable (click$) each time it receives an emission.
Instead of using a dedicated Subject for destroying, you can simply use the "unsub button click" observable as the trigger:
subBtnClick$.pipe(
  mergeMap(() => click$),
  takeUntil(unsubBtnClick$),
  share()
)

Here's a StackBlitz

Thanks for this. I think i tried something similar previously, but (and i don't understand why) it assigns a new addEventListener handler on each click of subscribe, instead of sharing the first one

Do you get the desired result if you replace the mergeMap with exhaustMap?

It looks like exhaustMap limits it to just one subscription. So clicking subscribe multiple times then clicking anywhere in the window only outputs one event, not multiple

Yes, it limits to one subscription to one inner subscription to click$, but you could then have multiple subscriptions to the outer subBtn$.pipe(...) observable. I guess I'm not totally clear on your desired behavior.

My apologises, you're absolutely right. I thought i'd written a clear list of the requirements, but reading them back, hadn't at all. It was implied in the solution code i'd written, which only means something to me. I've edited the question to hopefully make the requirements clearer

What I would do is make both click$ and destroy$ multicast:

click$ keeps emitting until destroy$ does.
listen$ keeps adding new listeners until destroy$ emits.

Once destroy$ emits, click$ completes and so does listen$ so new listeners cannot be added.
In the demo below:

The "Emit" button does nothing until you click on "Subscribe"
Keep clicking on "Emit" and "Subscribe".
Once you click on "Unsubscribe" both "Emit" and "Subscribe" won't do anything anymore.



let i = 0;
let j = 0;

const btn1 = document.querySelector('#btn1');
const btn2 = document.querySelector('#btn2');
const btn3 = document.querySelector('#btn3');

const destroy$ = fromEvent(btn3, 'click').pipe(
  take(1),
  share()
);

const click$ = fromEventPattern(
  handler => {
    console.log('click$: subscribing...');
    btn1.addEventListener('click', handler);
  },
  handler => {
    console.log('click$: unsubscribing...');
    btn1.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  }
).pipe(
  map(() => ++i),
  takeUntil(destroy$),
  share(),
);

const listen$ = fromEvent(btn2, 'click').pipe(
  takeUntil(destroy$)
);

listen$.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(`new logger (${++j})`);
  const logger = id => n => console.log(`logger ${id} -> ${n}`);
  click$.subscribe(logger(j));
});
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@%5E7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
const {
  fromEvent,
  fromEventPattern,
  map,
  share,
  takeUntil,
  take,
} = rxjs;
</script>

<button id="btn1">Emit</button>
<button id="btn2">Subscribe</button>
<button id="btn3">Unsubscribe</button>



